# Firebase crash reporting on iOS gives build error "symbolFileMappings:upsert: Request contains an invalid argument."

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to set up Firebase's new crash reporting [via their docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) and running into an error. When I build the project I get this error from the run script phase:

```
Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:384: error: symbolFileMappings:upsert: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

After debugging a bit I found the `VERBOSE` flag and set that for more info as seen below (keys removed)

```
/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:376: note: another thing
== Info:   Trying 216.58.216.47...
== Info: Connected to mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com (216.58.216.47) port 443 (#0)
== Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
== Info: Server certificate: *.googleapis.com
== Info: Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
== Info: Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
=> Send header, 413 bytes (0x19d)
0000: POST /v1/apps/1:000000000000:ios:0000000000000000/symbolFileMapp
0040: ings:upsert?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
0082: Host: mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com
00ad: User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
00c6: Accept: */*
00d3: Content-Type: application/json
00f3: X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier: com.jakecraige.Inventry
0125: Authorization: Bearer XXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
0165: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXX
0186: Content-Length: 186
019b: 
=> Send data, 186 bytes (0xba)
0000: {"upload_key":"1:000000000000:ios:0000000000000000-00000000-0000
0040: -0000-0000-000000000000","symbol_file_mapping":{"symbol_type":2,
0080: "app_version":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}
== Info: upload completely sent off: 186 out of 186 bytes
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<= Recv header, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: Vary: X-Origin
<= Recv header, 15 bytes (0xf)
0000: Vary: Referer
<= Recv header, 47 bytes (0x2f)
0000: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Mon, 30 May 2016 21:47:10 GMT
<= Recv header, 13 bytes (0xd)
0000: Server: ESF
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Cache-Control: private
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<= Recv header, 29 bytes (0x1d)
0000: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<= Recv header, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
<= Recv header, 69 bytes (0x45)
0000: Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,
0040: 25"
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: Accept-Ranges: none
<= Recv header, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 138 bytes (0x8a)
0000: 7f
0004: {.  "error": {.    "code": 400,.    "message": "Request contains
0044:  an invalid argument.",.    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT".  }.}.
0085: 0
0088: 
== Info: Connection #0 to host mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com left intact
/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:385: note: symbolFileMappings:upsert: The metadata for the symbol file failed to update.
```

So it looks like the POST to `mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com/v1/apps/$GOOGLE_APP_ID/symbolFileMappings:upsert?key=$FIREBASE_API_KEY` is failing.

Looking through all the params, they seem to match up with my config and nothing is empty, so I'm not really sure what to do next.

Has anyone else run into this? Idea on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the build report, when running on verbose=3 ('-vvv'), did you see something like the following lines?

```
CrashTestApp (architecture x86_64) symbol dump follows (first 20 lines):
MODULE mac x86_64 5FFC1B5C32CF33EEB4BFFA4189412AE30 CrashTestApp
FILE 0 /Applications/Xcode.app/…
⋮
FILE 4 /Users/me/Source/CrashTestApp/…
FUNC 1bf0 54 0 -[ViewController viewDidLoad]
1bf0 14 11 4
1c04 30 12 4
⋮
```

(The numbers and file names will obviously be different.) The key is the magic pattern in the first line: it must start with `MODULE` followed by the machine type and architecture (single words) followed by a 33 digit hex string, then the name of the app. If the file upload does not follow that pattern, then the upsert step fails.

Comment: Hey Robert, this is what I'm seeing for that line `MODULE mac x86_64 45FA3BDF3866336FACCE04D28744BAF30 Inventry`

Comment: I'm actually seeing two different strings like that, `MODULE mac x86_64 45FA3BDF3866336FACCE04D28744BAF30 Inventry` and `MODULE mac x86_64 45FA3BDF3866336FACCE04D28744BAF30 Inventry.FILE`, perhaps that second one is the culprit? There's something weird going on with newlines there. A bit more context here: https://gist.github.com/jakecraige/79ac463e7da0e5605bdf502bdd0edf47

Comment: @robert-menke I have the same issue, and verified after running on verbose=3 that the MODULE mac stuff was fine. *However*, it revealed the arguments being passed up for upsert, and one of them, `app_version` is that's causing the failure. In my case I was doing a debug build, and my debug build version is `3.7-dev` (i.e. not all numbers and dots). Changing this to `3.7` makes the upsert request complete successfully. I'd be interested to see if @jakecraige has a similar issue with the app version.

Comment: @RizwanSattar That was it! I had a [build script](https://github.com/thoughtbot/liftoff/blob/master/templates/bundle_version.sh) that sets the build number to a git commit hash so when I removed that and set to a standard version number it worked.

Comment: Sorry about that. The backend team rejects any version that is not in Dewey decimal format (`=~ m/^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$/`). It's not a valid restriction as the version is only used for labeling, but they felt it was necessary to filter out corrupted uploads.

Comment: Thanks for writing back @robert-menke. I figured it must be a restriction for some reason, though it hampers a common workflow for developers, as you know. Could you elaborate on the corrupted uploads? I'm not sure how a version string can help detect that. Regardless, I'd add an enhancement request to provide a more descriptive error message (than "contains invalid argument") when you guys get a chance. I've modified my  Script to only upload on Release builds, skipping debug builds.

Comment: The general idea at the time was that only formal release builds would be symbolicated, and anything not looking like a formal release would be held in suspicion. In retrospect, it was a poor decision—the version is used only for display purposes; the LC_UUID is the functional identifier. We are working on having that restriction removed so any arbitrary string would be accepted as a version identifier.